# Is it possible to modify the properties of a subclass from a parent class in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, properties, subclass, superclass

Via a method or closure, perhaps?

I created a subclass view controller of my superclass/parent view controller and placed labels with placeholder text in that subclass view controller.

I want to set the labels' values to blank strings from the superclass/parent view controller, or, specifically, from an IBAction function that causes the subclass view controller to appear.

Here is the code, first from the parent class, then from the subclass...

'''

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController {
            @IBAction func leavingView(){
                    self.EntryViewController.entryDateLabel.text = ""
                    self.EntryViewController.entryLabel.text = ""
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
```

'''
then from the subclass...
'''

```
  class EntryViewController: ViewController {

            @IBOutlet var entryDateLabel: UILabel!
            @IBOutlet var entryLabel: UILabel!
     }
```

'''

Comment: If the class you're attempting to subclass from is not `final`, then you should be able to. Whatever you're overriding will be marked `override` by Xcode.

Comment: if you are dismissing view controller in your `leavingView()` method then why you want to update labels?

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense Bilal... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with 2 solutions to this problem, without having the parent view controller know about its subclass.

In the first example the parent sets properties on itself that the child listens to (via the `didSet` method, it then updates its view accordingly. However, this isn't ideal because the `entryDate` and `entry` string fields are useless on their own, almost redundant in the parent.

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

    var entryDate: String?
    var entry: String?

    @IBAction func leavingView(){
        self.entryDate = ""
        self.entry = ""
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class ChildViewController: ParentViewController {

    @IBOutlet var entryDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var entryLabel: UILabel!

    override var entryDate: String? {
        didSet {
            guard isViewLoaded else {
                return
            }
            entryDateLabel.text = entryDate
        }
    }

    override var entry: String? {
        didSet {
            guard isViewLoaded else {
                return
            }
            entryLabel.text = entry
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion, the second solution is clearer and keeps implementation details more separate because you're using instructions or events to notify the child view controllers.

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func leavingView(){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: didLeaveView)
    }

    func didLeaveView() { }
}

class ChildViewController: ParentViewController {

    @IBOutlet var entryDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var entryLabel: UILabel!

    override func didLeaveView() {
        entryDateLabel.text = ""
        entryLabel.text = ""
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @GeovanniEscobar would you mind accepting this answer if it's answered your question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement is not that much clear I have created a demo for you and into that demo I have added child `ContainerViewController` into parent `ViewController` and from that parent view controller you can change `UILabel` text when you click on `UIButton` of parent `ViewController` and code will be for `ViewController`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func btnFromParentViewTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        //Here get the child of your parent view controller
        if let containerView = self.children[0] as? ContainerViewController {
            containerView.lblContainer.text = ""
        }
    }
}
```

and `ContainerViewController` code will be:

```
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblContainer: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

Don't need to add much here because you are accessing it from parent view.

And your result will be:

[image]

As you can see when I click on button which title says `Change Container label text` the label text from `ContainerViewController` set to empty string.

For more info check [THIS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=91130712801013974749) demo project.